# Test android webview html 5 app

Tags: android, html, google-app-engine, webview

Hello I am making an Google Appengine hosted HTML5 webapp.  It is going swell so far except that every time i want to test the webpage I have to upload it to the server so that my phone can go and get the url.

Is there any way to test a local server on my win machine on my webview??  I am really getting sick of having to upload it to appengine, seeing somethin minor wrong in the webview rendering and having to reupload it again.

Thanks

Ruben

Comment: Why aren't you just using a wifi connection on your local lan and connecting to the dev server  or use the android emulator or a local browser.

Comment: I hate using the emulator.  It doesn't represent (for me at least) anything close to what I get when I test on my phone.  Don't ask me why that is, just my experience.  I have tried the local lan thing but when I put in the GWT address that eclipse generates for testing my phone cannot find it.  It gives me http://127.0.0.1:8888/WebInvestCalc.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Comment: and a local browser (i am assuming you mean like *chrome??) doesn't have all the quirks in it that a webview does.  Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: PS - i understand on another computer you use 10.0.2.2 but I cannot access this with my phone on lan either.

Comment: He means run the dev server, and change your android code to point to your local machine running the dev server instead of the appengine server.

Comment: i can do that dragon, but then you have to use the emulator.  My phone can't access the dev server on my win machine.  Well it couldn't until danny answered.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on the emulator or on the same network, your win machine is the server.
You just need to get its IP by going to command prompt and writing the command `ipconfig`

And use this IP on your android application

For a more detailed way to get the ip : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49tYGwBhP3Y

Answer (score 1):

By default, the local dev server only allows connections from the same machine. If you want to use the Android emulator, that's fine (but it sounds like you don't want to use the emulator from the comments).

You should use the `--host` parameter (in recent versions of the SDK) to bind your server to an address that will be visible on your network, e.g.:

```
dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 .
```

Once you've done this, you can point your web view to the address of your machine on the LAN.